# Are a Bronze Dragon's breath attacks' cooldowns shared?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons, breath-weapon, recharge

A Bronze Dragon has two different breath weapons: a Line of Lightning, and a Repulsion Gas. The breath weapons of Dragons always come with a certain cooldown period.

I was wondering if using one of these breath weapons also meant the other one was on cooldown. Or is it possible to use one breath weapon first, and then the other one on the next turn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dragon cannot use the second breath weapon while the first is on cooldown. From the [breath weapon rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm#dragonBreathWeapons):

> Once a dragon breathes, it can’t breathe again until 1d4 rounds later. If a dragon has more than one type of breath weapon, it still can breathe only once every 1d4 rounds.